# Jquery ajax call: can't use numbers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have a pretty basic problem but I can't seem to figure it out...

This is my ajaxcall via jquery:

```
function noname(){

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'somefile.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){

            $('#user').text(data.info.name).fadeIn(500);


        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });

}
```

Let's say somefile.php outputs this:

```
{"proceed":"1","info":{"name":"John","online":"Online","id":"1"}}
```

In this case, everything works fine, and the user-div appears, containing the text "John".

However, let's say somefile.php outputs this:

```
{"proceed":"1","info":[{"id":"1","name":"John"},{"id":"2","name":"Rick"},{"id":"3","name":"Jane"},{"id":"4","name":"Astrid"}]}
```

To visualize it, here's the print_r of the array:

```
Array
(
[proceed] => 1
[info] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => John
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Rick
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => Jane
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [name] => Astrid
            )
    )
)
```

I want to output the same thing as I did in the working scenario, so I would put this in the ajax-call:

```
$('#user').text(data.info.0.name).fadeIn(500);
```

This gives an error, since I can't use numbers there.
Anyone knows how to handle this?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Use some dev tools to inspect the object. You'll see that those are array elements and not object properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since "info" is an array, you can simply access its entries like this:

```
data.info[0].name
```

Works the same for objects:

```
data['info'][0].name
```

Comment: You don't need the quotas, you can grab from array index as numeric: `data.info[0].name`

Comment: @GabrielGartz Ninja edit! (thanks, thought he was handling objects there)